# Why wont my Excel functions execute?

Tags: excel

I am having problems with excel 2013, where none of my functions will execute rather the cell will just present my formula...
has any one ran into this problem?
it is for all functions

Comment: Check cell properties, is it a text?

Answer (score 1):

Click on any cell containing a formula that displays the formula in both the cell and the Formula Bar and run this short macro:

```
Sub marine()
   If ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas Then
      ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = False
      Exit Sub
   Else
      ActiveCell.ClearFormats
      ActiveCell.Formula = ActiveCell.Formula
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub marine? That's certainly worth plus one.

Comment: @Bathsheba  ........Anything for a smile!

Answer (score 0):

You're in "display formulas" mode.

To untoggle this, hold the [Ctrl] key down and press that key just under [Esc] on the keyboard.

Comment: That would be a more eloquent way of saying it, yes.